# How to delete just the database from a specific Power Platform environment?

Tags: power-automate, power-platform, dataverse

I want to delete a Dataverse database from a Power Platform environment (being aware about potential functionality breaking risks).

Is it possible in current version of the platform (June 2021)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dataverse database is at the very core of a Power Platform environment. Without it the environment would not be functional at all. Therefore it cannot be deleted.